Does Dart's const keyword allocate memory for unrendered screens in Flutter?
In Flutter, or rather in Dart, const means that the value is determined at compile-time, but doesn't this mean that memory is allocated even for screens that aren't currently being rendered? In other words, my understanding is that memory for const values is allocated at app startup. Or am I misunderstanding this?

Anything that isn't referenced is tree-shaken (eliminated) in a release build.
So don't worry about importing things you never use, or only use a little bit of... it'll be compiled into the debug builds, but never the release build.
